Having trouble connecting to ChromerDriver
I am having trouble connecting my Selenium Java code to ChromeDriver. I was able to connect to GeckoDriver for Firefox, but now it's not working.
The error occurs in this line of code:
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

This is my full code.
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //path to chromedriver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/pathtodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Open a website
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("Title: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}

The code is supposed to open Google.
Here's a list of the jars I downloaded:

Guava, Junit, okhttp, selenium-api, selenium-chrome, selenium-java, selenium-remote-driver, selenium-support

I am working on a mac.
I triple checked my path. I tried looking online but I couldn't find anything.

How do you know it's 'not working'? What behavior is different than expected? Are there any errors?

I have had experiences with ChromeDriver being blocked by AV. Make sure you don't have any sort of AV running in the background that could be blocking the connection.
